# Pick group totals, grand totals and normal summarization in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate average of 2 columns in another column in Tableau but difficult part is grand total is not getting average instead it is the sum of 3rd calculated field.

```
  A    B   Calculated field

  10   5    2
  6    3    2
T 16   8    4 (Here I should get 2 instead it is taking sum of column)
```

Here I am unable to write separate formula for row totals and grand totals, Only one formula (Calculated Field) is allowed and when I am dragging on sheet it is by default aggregating to **sum**.

Note: I am expert in Crystal and BO but beginner in Tableau.

### Update

Code used for LoD

```
{FIXED [Product Category]: AVG([Sales])}
```

Below image is what I got after implementation I have tried with 2 columns but the result is same if I use only one column (I am trying to get the average of sales)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - the Grand Total by default does a **SUM** function you just have use the **Total All Using --> Average** option.

[image]

**Output :** Level wise SUM(Profit) later averaged across **columns** and **rows.** (Show Column Grand Total & Show Row Grand Total active)

[image]

**Update:** Answering the question below. To get the Row-wise avg (which is Cat1-vag in this case) you could just drop the measure and change it to AVG(). Since you needed in a Calculated Field you could use a Simple FIXED LOD. You can also **uncheck aggregated measures** from **Analysis** dropdown and have no Dimension in column or row like unlike what this example shows and still get three different averages. Cheers.

```
{FIXED [Cat1]:AVG([Profit])}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, will implement and let you know output. I have one more question here suppose Average of A row is 2 thats fine but if I want to extract that value of a table into a calculated field, How that is to be done? Also when a calculated field is dragged on to the sheet it is always aggregated. How can I stop it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was occupied in some other stuff will try and get back to you in few days. Thanks

Comment: I have implemented your suggetions. I am able to get what was required using your option 1 (Using Total All Using --> Average) but I am more interested in using LoD, When I have implementer your suggestion in update, Nothing was working for me all results are wrong, Updated question with image of what I have done, Could you please suggest and guide what I am doing wrong here? thanks. Please check the question updated with images with LoD

Comment: Fixed LOD would fix the granularity to the Field you mention and would not change depending on Dimensions you drop in the sheet. Any measure you drop should be aggregated ( in your case AVG) which is the easiest method. But if you still want them to be in separate Calc-field you have to write too many LOD's which is not really encouraged.

Comment: Thanks for reply but why any field if its average also aggrrgated to sum on dragging on to sheet. Can you help with background logic

Answer (score 1):

Check out this very smart work around from Joe Mako.
https://community.tableau.com/thread/112791

1. create a calc field like:

   ```
   IF FIRST()==0 THEN    
   WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Sales]),0,IIF(FIRST()==0,LAST(),0))  
   END
   ```
2. duplicate your Category field
3. place "Category (copy)" on the level of detail
4. set the compute using for the calc field pill to use "Category (copy)"

[image]

The window function in the calculated field only takes into account what's in the view, and aggregate based on those number.

Comment: @Iampbob thanks for the reply... will try and let you know

Comment: @Iampbob Thank you very much for the solution I have learned one more way of implepemting the LoD